# How to search the letter in array. I am making a hangman game in Java

Tags: java

There have two array, a and b.

Array a :

```
char wordchars[] = {'Ａ', 'Ｐ', 'Ｐ', 'Ｌ', 'Ｅ'};
```

Array b :

```
char chosen[] = {'Ａ', 'Ｂ', 'Ｃ', 'Ｄ', 'Ｅ', 'Ｆ', 'Ｇ', 'Ｈ', 'Ｉ', 'Ｊ', 'Ｋ', 'Ｌ', 'Ｍ', 'Ｎ', 'Ｏ', 'Ｐ', 'Ｑ', 'Ｒ', 'Ｓ', 'Ｔ', 'Ｕ', 'Ｖ', 'Ｗ', 'Ｘ', 'Ｙ', 'Ｚ'}
```

If I want to hide 2 random characters and print it in array a, for example ＡＰ＿Ｌ＿
How to make sure the letter of array b can be change to －ＢＣＤＥ－ＦＧＨＩＪＫ－ＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ.(it mean the letter has been used in array a)

I am sorry about my English is bad.

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to say

Comment: Your example is weird because it has 2 Ps but the user only guessed one? you probably want to fix that for clarity.

Comment: Thank for your remind, It has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to amend your full list of alphabet characters, after the user has guessed one. i.e. replace the guess with `-`.

An easier way to do this to use an `ArrayList`, and just check if it contains the guess, and if so, replace it with the `-`.

```
if (myList.contains(guess)) {
      myList.set(myList.indexOf(guess), "-");
}
```

For example, if the user guessed `D`, then the list becomes:

> A, B, C, -, E...

[See online example](https://ideone.com/jZcwm0)

Comment: I have update the post. I am sorry about my expression ability in english.